# Wordpress: How do I change the Site Logo next to the Site Title?

Tags: html, wordpress, web

I have looked around the internet for this specific issue and I cannot seem to find a fix for what my exact issue is. I want to replace the site logo that appears in, for example, a chrome tab that sits to the left of the site title.

I already put a meta tag override in the very top of the header but it failed to do anything.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/logo.png">
```

[image: example of issue]

The meta tag expands into a url that is able to be visited and seen, so I know it is not a bad url.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: _“I want to replace the site logo that appears in, for example, a chrome tab that sits to the left of the site title.”_ - that is simply the _Favicon_ of the site, and with most themes you can specify it via the Customizer.

Comment: And if you want the favicon to show in the backend as well, for example in the list under “my websites”, then you can get that functionality for example via a plugin such as https://github.com/bueltge/wordpress-multisite-enhancements WP calls this a “blavatar”, so presumably that stands for blog avatar … If you want to change it yourself, without using a 3rd-party plugin, then check if there’s any hooks/filters relating to that name maybe.

Comment: Thank you both so much, I think I can investigate this further properly now!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the theme you use it should be available in the Customize menu (top bar), then Site identity and Site icon section. Selected graphics needs to be square and at least 512x512px large.

Comment: I am using a custom theme, one I created, is there any way you could point me in the direction of enabling all of that in my theme or doing it directly in html / css / php?